# How do I compare a string to all items in a listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating an application that allows the user to store information about their classes. There is a button in my application that allows the user to enter information and if it matches any item in the `listBox` then it should display information about it.

I can only get it to work if I specify a particular item by position (e.g. `Items[0]`) of the `listBox` and then convert it to a string. My aim is to compare all items in the `listBox`.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox2.Items[0].ToString() == "PersonalInfo")
    {
        label.Text = "test";               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to loop through all of the items in the list. Try something like this:

```
foreach(var item in listBox2.Items)
{
  if(item.ToString() == stringToMatch)
  {
    label.Text = "Found a match";
  }
}
```

An alternate, simpler implementation (which will stop if/when it finds a match instead of continuing to check every item) would be

```
if(listBox2.Items.Any(item => item.ToString() == stringToMatch))
{
  label.Text = "Found a match";
}
```

Comment: Note that the first version is interchangeable between WinForms and WebForms, but I wasn't able to get the bottom one to work with WebForms. I thought it might just need `using System.Linq;` but that was not sufficient.

Comment: OP explicitly mentions in the question they're hardcoding a check for position [0] as part of the explanation of the problem. The answer is better when it doesn't regurgitate that information.

Answer (score 6):

Write a loop to check each item

```
foreach(var item in listBox2.Items)
{
  if (item.ToString()== "PersonalInfo")
  {
     label.Text = "test";
     break; // we don't want to run the loop any more.  let's go out              
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well you could use LINQ... something like this:

```
if (listBox2.Items
            .Cast<object>()
            .Select(x => x.ToString())
            .Contains("PersonalInfo"))
{
    label.Text = "test";
}
```

Or if you want to get the details of the first match:

```
var match = listBox2.Items
                    .Cast<object>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToString() == "PersonalInfo");
if (match != null)
{
    // Use match here
}
```

Comment: I don't think the lambda expression is necessary. Simply doing ListBox.Items.Contains(StringValue) should work.

Comment: @Matt - I was thinking the same thing, but I believe the issue is that Items is a collection of `Object`s that need to be `ToString`ed for comparison (my guess).

Comment: @Matt: You need the `Cast` call in order to use the rest of LINQ, and you're assuming that it already *is* a string.

Comment: My answer got accepted over Jon Skeet's? There should be a badge for that!

Comment: @Jim, readability helps a lot, some people don't like/understand lambdas.

Comment: im a bit of a newbie at programming and Jim and Shyjus answer was alot easier too understand for me - if i could give two ticks i would

Comment: @Shyju: Using `==` almost certainly *won't* work. `ListBox.Items[n]` would return an `object`, so `==` would perform a *reference* comparison. It's possible that `Equals` would work, but you can't possibly know, as we don't know what the contents of the `ListBox` is. The value might not be a string - it might be some business object which overrides `ToString` to return one part of the object.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes. I just did an example(with string as list items) and the debugger showed object { string} http://i46.tinypic.com/2eqceua.png. I guess(after reading your comment) it is because my list items are of string type. Thanks for throwing some light. :) i will delete my comment as it will spread wrong information.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thats why I up-voted your answer, obviously I'm not the only one that didn't consider the possibility in this context of the ListItem not being of a string type, and your answer addresses that issue the best in my opinion.